# Given an unsorted array A, check if A[i] = i exists efficiently

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

Given array A, check if A[i] = i for any i exists.

I'm supposed to solve this faster than linear time, which to me seems impossible. The solution I came up with is to first sort the array in n*log(n) time, and then you can easily check faster than linear time. However, since the array is given unsorted I can't see an "efficient" solution?

Comment: Even if you sort, it is more costly than linear time.

Comment: You are right, this cannot be done faster than in linear time on an unordered array.

Comment: if A is sorted, a binary search will be faster than linear time. If you don't have any information about A, it isn't possible since any element could match.

Comment: You can't possibly show that an array doesn't satisfy the condition without checking every element, which is linear. Are you sure that there wasn't any other assumptions on A?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight only true for constant number of processors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can't have* a correct algorithm with better than `O(N)` complexity for an arbitrary (unsorted) array.

Suppose you have the solution better than `O(N)`. It means that the algorithm has to *omit* some items of the array since scanning all the items is `O(N)`.

Construct `A` such that `A[i] != i` for all `i` then run the algorithm. 
Let `A[k]` be the item which has been omitted. Assign `k` to `A[k]`,
run the algorithm again - it'll return `no such items` when `k` is expected.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I expected! Thanks for proving it to me :). My professor must have made some mistake.

Comment: Not true. There is no such algorithm if you're limited to a constant number of processors. Tht's theonly case where the give proof holds. If you have sqrtN processors, I'll gve you a O(sqrt N) algorithm. @ALEXANDERWORMBS

Comment: @BastianJ : Your argument doesn't make sense at all. In which universe do you have access to an unlimited amount of processors? You could also claim that every algorithm is O(1).

Comment: @EricDuminil While the first sentence is quite offensive, the last statement is just wrong. The question is tagged "computer-science" and "algorithms". It uses Landau notation, so we're talking asymptotical (and of course theoretical) bounds. We do not assume the input to be limited (where do you get the unlimited memory from?), so why shouldn't we talk about unlimited processors? This is part of CS, believe it or not.

Comment: @EricDuminil Also, there is a very practical point in proving the time complexity bounds for unlimited processors: These bounds are the final bounds for parallelization. The insight that the given problem _can_ be solved in log n time with n processors implies that you can use a very naive parallelization that gives you almost optimal speedup unless. If you have 100 processors, you get 100 times faster (on large inputs).

Comment: We'll just have to agree to disagree. O(n/100) is still O(n).

Comment: @EricDuminil "You could also claim that every algorithm is O(1)." This is wrong in at least two ways. First, a claim that "every algorithm is [runs] in O(1)" is obviously nonsense, as everyone knows algorithms which do not. I assume you were trying to say "you could claim that every problem can be solved in O(1)" [skipping all the formal blabla]. Also, this is nonsense. This specific problem is easy to solve in parallel because there's an O(1)-size subset can witness the desired property.

Comment: It was a (bad) joke to show that your argument is absurd. Feel free to assume infinite processors, I'll keep on rejecting any "proof" which cannot tell the difference between 100 and infinity.

Comment: @EricDuminil "O(n/100) is still O(n)." Of course. That's not the point. The statement I made was stronger and implies this kind of speedup not only for a constant number of processors. Also, what's wrong with unlimidet processors in a universe of unlimited memory? If this "argument doesn't make sense at all", then why are there lectures covering precisely the implications of such computational models such as PRAM?

Comment: @EricDuminil " I'll keep on rejecting any "proof" which cannot tell the difference between 100 and infinity." The example of 100 was an _application_ of the statement which does not talk about any numbers at all.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get O(log n) with a parallel algorithm (you didn't restrict that). Just start N processors in ld(N) steps and let them check the array items in parallel.

Comment: Sure! And you can solve knapsack problem in O(1) with 2**n processors, so it must be O(1), right? And use faster processors, it will become O(0.5)!

Comment: @EricDuminil Sorry for being blunt, but you don't seem to know what you are talking about. I gave a parallel algorithm with O(log n) time complexity. I am quite confident that this is _exactly_ the answer the OP's professor was asking for.
Your claim that someone could solve the knapsack problem with in O(1) time complexity is just plain wrong. Try to prove it. No chance.
And your try to make fun of me by abusing O-notation is both silly and insulting. I did my Phd in the field. Prove my statement wrong that there is a parallel algorithm with O(log n) time complexity or be quiet.

Comment: Side note: I claim that basically for every function f in o(n), there is an algorithm that uses f processors and O(n/f(n)) time. That includes the case of sqrt(N) processors and O(sqrt(N)) time.

Comment: Shouldn't `f(n)` be bounded, or do you really assume that an infinity of processors are available?

Comment: As long as we assume unlimited input, we can as well assume unlimited processors. This is not a discussion about the fastest implementation in some language. This is a question from an algorithms class. It's the kind of answer I would expect clever students to come up with in my classes. It's nothing uncommon. If you start talking Big-O-notation, you're in the world of abstract machines, such as Turing machine, but also of PRAM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_random-access_machine)